# Using rasberry pi to transmit audio from Laptop to mixing board

Tags: audio

I want to send audio from my pc (connected to a private LAN) to a Rasberry pi device that I connect the audio input connection on my mixing console. This needs to be done over a wired LAN.

Here’s the situation. I’m setting up sound for a live play/show. The mixer and Mics will be on the stage. I will have 1 Cat5 cable from the stage to the sound booth connecting the mixer to a router. I control the mixer with a Behringer xtouch compact (fader controls) that is also connected to the router. The issue I have is the sound effects and music will need to be controlled by a laptop in the sound booth. So I need to transmit the audio output back to the mixing board over the LAN. Wireless will not work due to distance and interference.

I know of expensive systems such as Daunte and AVB that do this. But I was hoping to be able to do this much cheaper using a Raberry Pi.

Is this possible?

Comment: your problem is fully described in the first half of the first sentence in the first paragraph .... `I want to send audio from my pc (connected to a private LAN) to a Rasberry` ...... the rest of the post introduces confusion into your post, especially the second paragraph, because it has nothing to do with the problem ....... you have not said what operating system is on the laptop ...... please ask a simple question without any extra unnecessary information

Comment: Jsotola, I asked for help not criticism. I explained the goal to ward off the suggestions of why don’t I just use Bluetooth or a wireless solution. But thanks for pointing out my blunder and helping me in THAT way.

Comment: i am not criticizing ..... i had to read your post several times before it became clear what you are asking ..... there is no difference between wired and wireless LAN connections as far as the transport of data .... one may be slower because of dropouts and re-transmits therefore not suitable for real-time application  ..... if you stream the audio over LAN then the receiving software would be completely unaware of how the data has arrived ...... all you need is a server that streams audio to LAN and a player that receives the audio stream from LAN